# Podcast App Subscription Doesn't Match iTunes Store

Tags: ios, iphone, rss, itunes, podcast

I have a podcast that shows the latest episodes and updates when I go to the iTunes Store (Desktop and iPhone), however, after I subscribe to the podcast on the Podcast App (iPhone), it shows my old podcast feed that I had before I moved my podcast to another domain.

- Yes, I did do a 301 redirect to the new RSS feed
- Yes, I did do a new itunes feed tag
- Yes, this only affects the Podcast app on the iPhone

The Podcast in question is called Super Coach by Coach Micheal Burt.

Any suggestions?

Brandon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being fixed by changing the feed URL inside of the new Podcast Connect dashboard on podcastconnect.apple.com website.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually reset the iTunes feed at the site listed above. Here is mine; verify (highlighted) that the 'cast is "active" and click on "refresh feed" also highlighted. It can never hurt to run an RSS feedreader test. w3c provides excellent QA.[image: sample podcast connect data]